# Shortest way to bind a certain amout of items from a list to a data source?

Tags: c#, list

Anyone know how to select a certain amount of items in a List to bind to a DataSource? Basically I'm getting back 10 items (which I don't have control over) and I only need to show 5. Originally I was thinking of using a loop and adding 5 items to a new list but that seems like a lot of code. Is there an expression that I can use to select the first 5?

```
//Returns a List<DataItem>
MyDataListControl.DataSource = Helper.GetDataItems(); //<= Possible expression?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) LINQ extension methods. So in your case if you wanted to take only the first 5 elements of some `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
MyDataListControl.DataSource = Helper.GetDataItems().Take(5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `List`'s `GetRange` method? Have you tried that? I don't the internal workings of the method; whether it also creates a new list or not.

```
GetRange(int index, int count)
```

Here is the [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) for it.

Comment: I just checked and the efficiency of the method is O(n) where n is the count: number of elements you want, in your case 5. But since you said 'it seems like a lot of code' and you are not so worried about the time efficiency then this method reduces your code

Answer (score 1):

RemoveRange will probably be best as you won't have to instanciate a new list, unless that happens internally anyway.. Just make sure you're always getting 10 items or you'll potentially get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

```
list.RemoveRange(5, 5);
```

That should leave you with the first five items.